# Set spark executor ip address

Tags: apache-spark

In my current setup, there's two networks that each spark node has access to: an internal one connecting each of the nodes that's blazing fast, and an external one that can connect to other machines but is slow.  The problem is that, even with setting SPARK_LOCAL_IP to be the internal ip address, all traffic goes through the slow public network according to nload.  However, the references in the web ui are all to the internal ip address, as well as the references in the log messages (192.168.xx.xx is the internal network):

```
INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command:...
    "--hostname" "192.168.xx.xx" "--cores" "16"
     "--app-id" "app-xxxxx-yyyy" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.xx.xx:12344"
```

Do I have to change the hostname to correspond with the internal ip address, or is there a better way to configure the spark executor nodes to pass traffic through the internal network while having the public hostname correspond to the slower external network?

Comment: The way we do is to resolve the hostname to internal ip by adding to /etc/hosts